# Reading data from JSON file in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, json, html, angularjs

Hai i am new in Angularjs. I am trying to read data from JSON file, But it returns a strange output. 
Here is my controller.js file

```
angular
.module('app')
.controller('homeCtrl',function($scope,Friend){
      $scope.friends=Friend.get();
      console.log("DATA FROM JSON:",$scope.friends);
      $scope.title="Home";       

})
```

Here is my services.js file

```
angular
.module('app')
.factory('Friend',function($http){

   return {
    get:function(){

            console.log("inside function");
            return [


            $http.get('/api/get.json').then(function(msg){

                return msg.data;    
            })
           ]          
        }
   }
})
```

console output is

```
DATA FROM JSON: 
[Object]
0: Object
length: 1
__proto__: Array[0
```

Please help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**$http.get** returns a promise and you're returning an array containing that promise.

Do this instead:

```
angular
.module('app.services', [])
.factory('Friend', function ($http) {
    return {
        get: function () {
            console.log("inside function");
            return $http.get('/api/get.json');
        }
    };
});
```

Then use your factory this way:

```
.angular
.module('app.controllers', ['app.services'])
.controller('yourCtrl', function ($scope, Friend) {
    Friend.get().then(function (msg) {
        $scope.msg = msg;
    });
});
```

Comment: It  works fine when i change argument msg to msg.data,thanks bro.

Comment: Can you give an answer for this? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25831459/pushnotifcation-in-phongap-android-multiple-registrion-ids-of-the-same-device)