# how to use the get() function in the $http service

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-http

I learning the $http service but I am not clear on this regarding the get(). below code doesn't execute demo2.htm. Please check and advise where i made the mistake.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('urlCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('demo2.htm').then(function(response) {
      $scope.myWelcome = response.data;
  });
});
```

Comment: is the controller even used? if it doesnt execute, the controller might not be loaded

Comment: Default dataType is *"json"* but you are getting a `.htm` file. What are you trying to do with it? Add an error handler for situations like this also

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25439674/reading-data-from-json-file-in-angularjs

Comment: I would like to view another HTML file in the present file using the $http.get() function

Comment: I have seen the following website for learning "http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_http.asp"

Comment: it contain few welcome information.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the `$http` service is not what you're looking for if you're trying to access a resource from the same location as your html/js files. One of the following should better suit your situation:

- [ngInclude](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude)
- [ngBindTemplate](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindTemplate)
- [ngRoute](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute)

Answer (score -1):

**Try this**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('urlCtrl', [
    '$scope',
    '$http',
    function($scope, $http) {
      $http.get('demo2.htm').then(function(response) {
          $scope.myWelcome = response.data;
      }
}]);
```

Comment: Thanks, the same code will run on the w3c tutorial but on my local system showing an issue.

Comment: <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="urlCtrl"> 

<p>Today's welcome message is:</p>
<h1>{{myWelcome}}</h1>

</div>var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('urlCtrl', [
    '$scope',
    '$http',
    function($scope, $http) {
      $http.get('demo2.htm').then(function(response) {
          $scope.myWelcome = response.data;
      }
}]);

Comment: Because you're running it locally, it can't make that request. You can use [http-server](https://github.com/indexzero/http-server) to fix this, and read here how to get started with angular https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial