# Repeat a div or span according to the json value using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, json

Suppose i have a json file as

```
{  
   "count":"3"
}
```

how to show 3 span  or "n" number of span according to json value

here is my [Plunker url](https://embed.plnkr.co/Gosf7WcKYS8WV8qC7i5u/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Way to ng-repeat defined number of times instead of repeating over array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16824853/way-to-ng-repeat-defined-number-of-times-instead-of-repeating-over-array)

Comment: @Sreekanth  hi ., here is the plunker demo i want to show star instead of numbers .. can you provide a detailed answer https://embed.plnkr.co/Gosf7WcKYS8WV8qC7i5u/

Answer (score 2):

CONTROLLER

```
var app = angular.module('myapp',[]);
app.controller('ctrlParent',function($scope){
    $scope.count =3;    
    $scope.getNumber = function(num) {
        return new Array(num);   
    }
});
```

HTML

```
   <li ng-repeat="i in getNumber(myNumber) track by $index"><span>{{$index+1}}</span></li>
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sh0ber/cHQLH/)**

Comment: hi ., here is the plunker demo i want to show star instead of numbers .. can you provide a detailed answer embed.plnkr.co/Gosf7WcKYS8WV8qC7i5u

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.number = 5;
$scope.getNumber = function(num) {
    return new Array(num);   
}

<ul>
<li ng-repeat="i in getNumber(number)"><span>{{$index+1}}</span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: sorry for the wrg url ., here is the plunker demo i want to show star instead of numbers .. can you provide a detailed answer embed.plnkr.co/QRB5v2cI6SZOdZgdqDVR/preview

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean. But according to my view, you have 2 problems: 
1. Read count in json file
2. Show n span in view.

- To read a json file, you can create a service to get it. Follow this [Reading data from JSON file in Angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25439674/reading-data-from-json-file-in-angularjs)
- Show show those span, use ng-repeat:
  Hello world
  count is $scope variable in ur controller.

Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

You could simply do this.

```js
var app = angular.module("sampleApp", []);

app.controller("sampleController", ["$scope",
  function($scope) {

    $scope.pro = [{
      product: "chicken",
      rating: 3
    }, {
      product: "fish",
      rating: 1
    }, {
      product: "pizza",
      rating: 4
    }];

    $scope.repeat = function(rating) {
      return new Array(rating);
    }
  }
]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="sampleApp">
  <div ng-controller="sampleController">
    <div ng-repeat="array in pro">
      <div>{{array.product}}
        <span ng-repeat="number in repeat(array.rating) track by $index" ng-init="">*</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    </body>
  </div>
</div>
```